# Replacing values in Dataframe based on data from a DataFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to replace the entries in a pandas `DataFrame` with an aggregated value that is "grouped" by an identifier in another column, but am unsure on how to do it correctly.

**Data**

Let's say I have a pandas `DataFrame` object that contains many duplicate `id` entries and some corresponding values:

```
df
  unique_id       id       value
      r1_c1       c1           9
      r2_c1       c1           3
      r3_c1       c1           4
     r1_c10      c10          10
     r2_c10      c10           9
     r3_c10      c10          25
        ...      ...         ..
   r2_c1000    c1000           8
   r4_c1000    c1000          10
```

and a `DataFrameGroupBy` object with unique `id` entries with aggregated (mean) values from the `DataFrame` entries grouped by `id`:

I.e:

```
mean_values = df.groupby(["id"]).mean()
mean_values
            id           value
            c1               3
           c10               4
           ...             ...
         c1000               5
```

I.e its shape is `1000 x 2` -- and can be seen as a dictionary/hash_table that maps `id -> (mean) value`.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

Essentially, I'm trying to replace all the `value` entries of an `id` in the original `DataFrame` object based on its mean value that I have in the `DataFrameGroupBy` object. So for instance, all `c1` in the original `DataFrame` object should have the value 3, `c10` with 4 etc:

```
df
  unique_id       id       value
      r1_c1       c1           3
      r2_c1       c1           3
      r3_c1       c1           3
     r1_c10      c10           4
     r2_c10      c10           4
     r3_c10      c10           4
        ...      ...         ...
   r2_c1000    c1000           5
   r4_c1000    c1000           5
```

But I don't know how to achieve this in pandas. Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Your looking for transform: `df['value'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('mean')`

Comment: Ah yes that is almost what I want! Do you know what I have to do, if I also want to preserve the other columns in the Dataframe?

Comment: Just set it equal to a new column. ie `df['avg_value'] = ...`

Comment: Oh yea that works - thanks a lot!